# Favicon shows in tab header but not when create a shortcut by dragging from the url bar

Tags: shortcut, favicon

My favicon displays next to the title on the tab when I have my webpage open.  That part is working properly.

I have a workflow where the user can drag anchor tags to create hyperlinks to specific elements on my site and those dragged links arent coming through with the favicon.

For instance: If you click and drag a link to this stackoverflow page to your desktop, the stackoverflow favicon is the icon that shows up on your desktop.  If you dont know what I mean, on windows click and drag the Lock icon next to the url onto your desktop and it will create a shortcut that shortcut will have the stackoverflow favicon as it's icon.

When I do this on my website, it shows the google chrome icon instead of the website favicon.

**Update:** **A more detailed description of what I'm doing and my results so far.**

When I use Chrome, I can never get the drag to use the favicon or apple-touch-icon.  But when I use firefox, it will use the apple-touch-icon when dragging from the lock in the address bar, and it will use the favicon with a white background when dragging an anchor tag to the desktop.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is support hard links to files the user has created in a web app that has a file manager built in. So the file manager in the app displays all your files, you can drag anchor tags associated with those file to your computers explorer folder structure, and when you launch that link from your computers folder structure, it will navigate straight to that file in the web app (bypassing the app's file manager)  So the two things I'm trying to support are

- icon when the anchor tag is dragged to the host machine (partially working in firefox and IE 11, not working in chrome,)
- apply a custom name for the shortcut (working in chrome it displays the text after the final slash of the url formatted to convert %20's to spaces , not in firefox it just displays the full url, partially working in IE11 it displays the text after the slash but includes %20's instead of spaces)

Answer (score 2):

**Quick solution**

Generate your favicon with [RealFaviconGenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/). The icons and code it generates work with desktop shortcuts (look at [compatibility test results](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility), "PC/Chrome" line and Homescreen column). Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.

**Longer solution and more details**

I reproduced the procedure you described (drag the lock of this page of StartOverflow, etc.) and this is what I get:

[image]

But if I use More Tools > Create shortcut, now the link is using SO's icon. Maybe this is the scenario you would like to support?

[image]

When creating this icon, Chrome picks the 180x180 Apple Touch icon if it finds it. In other words, you can fix your issue by creating and declaring this icon in your site.

Comment: interesting, I was going to comment my findings but they were too long, see my edit of the original question.